# Java Security Policy file is not being enforced

Tags: java, java-security

I've a little java code that writes a string to a file. I've created a .java.policy file in my home directory in ubuntu with the following contents:

```
/* AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED ON Mon Jun 24 11:27:02 IST 2019*/
/* DO NOT EDIT */

grant codeBase "" {
  permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read";
};

grant codeBase "file:/home/ScienceGuy/Desktop/Testing/javasecurity/*" {
  permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read";
};
```

When I run my java code, it simply creates the file and writes the string. I expect it to fail because the policy gives it read only access to files. How can I make the policy file work?

I tried to edit the java.security file and check the url.2 line to make sure it points to the policy file. Doesn't help.

Comment: You will need to add ` -Djava.security.manager=<ploicy>` to activate security manager while running the code.

Comment: Tried this without success:
java FileTest -Djava.security.manager=/home/ScienceGuy/.java.policy

Comment: The "grant codeBase "" ..." block doesn't look right, I would remove that. Also, the java.security.manager system property does not take a policy file. Try "java -Djava.security.manager <app>". The $HOME/.java.policy file is loaded by default. If this doesn't work try adding -Djava.security.debug=policy,access to dump some debug information.

Comment: Tried these things. No effect. No policies are enforced.

Comment: On windows, the command java -Djava.security.manager gives an error: class .security.manager not found. That is funny.